# Playing a sound when clicking on an image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-audio

I have a wordpress page where I would like sound to be played when an image is clicked. I got the code from this tutorial:

http://iwebfaq.org/site/iWeb_Sound_effects.html

Basically, I edited the page and added this in the text editor:

```
    <script>
// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)

var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"mp4": "audio/mp4",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
"wav": "audio/wav"
}
function createsoundbite(sound){
var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
}
html5audio.load()
html5audio.playclip=function(){
html5audio.pause()
html5audio.currentTime=0
html5audio.play()
}
return html5audio
}
else{
return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
}
}

var mouseoversound1=createsoundbite("http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/island_music_x.mp3")
var clicksound1=createsoundbite("http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/island_music_x.mp3")

</script>
```

And after that I add this:

```
<a nohref onclick="clicksound1.playclip()"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ananas.png" style="width:126px;height126px;border:0px;"></a>
```

What am I doing wrong? Nothing happens when I apply this, the image shows up but clicking on it does absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, I tired it with an oder mp3 file. The mp3 source does not exist (or the url is wrong). If you change it, the script will work.

Comment: I've checked the links multiple times but it still won't work. Perhaps my theme doesn't support HTML5? I'll check it out

Comment: To be sure, I suggest try with [http://www.banchieri.hu/krudy/02%20-%20Track%20%202.mp3 ] . And check, you start the html file with '<!DOCTYPE html>'

Comment: Nope, it won't work... Tried your link, it works fine if used as a separate audio media file in a theme, but otherwise nothing happens. I added <!DOCTYPE html> to the beginning of the page and also added 'add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list' ) );' to my functons.php as it wasn't there before... still nothing.